# Change DataType for the DataColumn of DataTable after filling the data and updating the rows

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I am making the query to `SQL server to get the data and store the data in the DataTable.`

I had lot of encrypted columns in the database 
**E.g** *DateOfBirth is encrypted.*

After i get the data i make the columns encrypted like `foreach(DataRow in datatable.rows)`

Now the problem is then i need to apply filters for `int and datetime.`

But the filters are failing because when the data is encrypted so the columns default datatype is string and the condition like  `DOB > 'say 1-1-2013'` does not work.

May be creating a clone may help but is there any easy solution

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hi, they are encrypted in the database. I get them into the datatable and then decrypt in foreach loop. And now i want to apply filters for columns which are previously encrypted but not in plain text. Since the column type is string previously so my >, < operator does not work for int, dateteim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue i created a new DataTable using clone method. Set the datatype for the particular column and then start filling the rows from the old datatable to new datatable.

The strange thing is i need to do is to accept changes

dtOld.AcceptChanges();

as i had made changes in the old database.

Answer (score 2):

If your queries consist only of equality comparisons then you can also encrypt the search criteria string e.g.,

When you are looking for users with DateOfBirth '1-1-2013' first encrypt this date and then search in the database.

However, I think you might loose the purpose of encrypting data in the first place with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You have to encrypt the data by which you are filtering the datatable, hopefully this may resolve your issue.